# Mixing columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mixing

I have a 2x100 matrix. It contains 100 elements from 2 different classes. So each element consists of the value itself and the label with the class it belongs to(1 or 2). I want to mix this data into another 2x100 matrix, where the values stay still connected to their labels.

An example with a 2x5 matrix would be:

```
 A=[1 2 3 4 5;
    1 2 2 2 1]
```

After mixing:

```
A=[2 3 5 1 4;
   2 2 1 1 2]
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index the entire columns (and randomly change the order using [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html))

```
Amix = A( :, randperm(size(A,2)) );
```

See an example [at ideone](https://ideone.com/jIIkEh).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help!